# A box contains 6 pagers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume any pager selected from the box is done randomly, and hence
selections are **independent** from each other. The probability of a selected pager being defective is 0.25.
Let X be the random variable for the number of defective pagers.

**A**) Determine the probability of selecting exactly 2 defective pagers.
**B**) Determine the probability of selecting at **least** 5 defective pagers. 

I tried P(X = 2) = 0.25^2, but I'm not sure if that's the correct approach for A)

Comment: How *many* selections are made?

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about the number of selection, so assume, that you selected 2 pagers exactly at once in A, and 5 at once in B.

Comment: That's not really what the wording of the question suggests.  ("exactly 2", "at least 5").

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is mkay, but really hinges on how many selections are made in total.

You are making some number, $\bbox[wheat,1pt]n$, of selections, and each with an *independent* rate of $0.25$ for being defection.

The count of defectives should thus have *a recognisable* distribution.

> $$\mathsf P(X=x) = {^n\mathrm C_x}~0.25^x~0.75^{(n-x)}$$ 
>
>  $$\mathsf P(X\leq x) = \sum_{k=0}^x{^n\mathrm C_k}~0.25^k~0.75^{(n-k)} = 1-\mathsf P(X>x)$$

Comment: So I plugged n = 6, because that's the number of samples, and x  = 2. I get 35% as the chance of exactly two items selected being defective. Does this make sense? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Struggling Not sure how you are getting that. $$\dfrac{6!}{2!~4!}\dfrac{1^2\,3^4}{4^6} = \dfrac{1215}{4096} = 0.296630859375$$